# The principle of geth checking whether a block has the highest total difficulty

Tags: go-ethereum

How and when does geth check whether there is any block not with the highest total difficulty in chain and rollback? What is the principle of it? 
If the location of source code for it could be provided，so much the better. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about the exact mechanics of how that works, but the `Rollback()` function can be found in [`blockchain.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/629b5837e99ced620e71f5d750f2c1abc3537ed3/core/blockchain.go#L640). (There's also a version for the "light" client, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ca376ead88a5a26626a90abdb62f4de7f6313822/light/lightchain.go#L321).)

```
// Rollback is designed to remove a chain of links from the database that aren't
// certain enough to be valid.
func (bc *BlockChain) Rollback(chain []common.Hash) {
...
```

Comment: Do you know where the Rollback() function of blockchain.go is invoked? I search with Rollback key word, but can not find the code that invoke this function except testing code.